# String representation of objects as in Scala REPL

Tags: scala

Is there a simple way to convert a Scala object to the string representation given in the REPL? For example, for `Array(2, 3, 5)`, I'd like to get the string `"Array(2, 3, 5)"`, and for `Stream from 2`, I'd like to get `"Stream(2, ?)"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The REPL uses the `toString` method to generate its string representations of values.  Thus:

```
Array(1, 2, 3).toString      // => "Array(1, 2, 3)"
```

This works on all versions of Scala (2.7, 2.8, etc).

Comment: Ah, I was assuming that `println` would use `toString`, but apparently on scala.Array, it doesn't.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's a lot of magic going on surround both `Array` and `toString`.  The `println` method just delegates to `System.out.println` (on the JVM) and so the result is whatever the *Java* implementation of `toString` is for that particular object.  Scala intercepts `toString` when it knows something is an `Array`, but it can't do that when the method call in question is inside Java code.

Comment: I'm a year late, but this is not how it works, which you can verify pretty easily by putting Array(1, 2, 3).toString into a 2.8 repl.

Answer (score 2):

The more usual way is to use the mkString method of Array (same in 2.7 and 2.8):

```
scala> val a1 = Array(1, 2, 3)
a1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)

scala> a1.mkString
res0: String = 123

scala> a1.mkString(", ")
res1: String = 1, 2, 3
```